# How to create an unsubscribe page in magento

Tags: magento, newsletter, unsubscribe

I would like to create a direct unsubscribe page in magento, I found this instruction to follow but the steps 1 and 2 are not clear As I'm not a professional.
Can someone please help me clarify these two steps. Where to create the "unsubscribe.phtml" page? How to add the just created block in it?
Thank you in advance.
 1. Create a phtml page say “unsubscribe.phtml” containing the code to create the unsubscribe form.

```
<?php $newsletterObj = new Mage_Newsletter_Block_Subscribe(); ?>
<div class="newsletter-unsubscribe">
<div class="newsletter-unsubscribe-title"><?php echo $this->__('Submit your email id to unsubscribe newsletter') ?></div>
<form action="<?php echo $newsletterObj->getUnsubscribeFormActionUrl() ?>” method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
<div class="block-content">
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>” class="input-text required-entry validate-email” value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter Your Email Here') ?>” onfocus="if(this.value==’<?php echo $this->__('Enter Your Email Here') ?>’)this.value=’’;” onblur="if(this.value==’’)this.value=’<?php echo $this->__('Enter Your Email Here') ?>’;”
/>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>” class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript\">
//<![CDATA[
var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm(’newsletter-validate-detail’);
//]]>
</script>
</div>
```

2) Create a CMS page. Add the just created block in it. So that your CMS page will contain that form.

3) Now in page \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\newsletter\subscribe.phtml add the code to add a link of the cms page.

```
<div class="unsubscribe">
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('unsubscribe-newsletter') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Unsubscribe') ?></a>
</div>
```

4) In page \app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe.php add a function to create the form action url which is called in the “unsubscribe.phtml”.

```
public function getUnsubscribeFormActionUrl()
{
return $this->getUrl(’newsletter/subscriber/unsubscribecus’, array(’_secure’ => true));
}
```

5) Now in \app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\controllers\SubscriberController.php page add new action for unsubscribe process.

/**
* Unsubscribe newsletter from frontend
*/

```
public function unsubscribecusAction()
{
$email = $this->getRequest()->getParam(’email’);
$subsModel = Mage::getModel(’newsletter/subscriber’);
$subscriber = $subsModel->loadByEmail($email);

$id = (int) $subsModel->getId();
$code = (string) $subsModel->getCode();
if ($id && $code) {
$session = Mage::getSingleton(’core/session’);
try {
Mage::getModel(’newsletter/subscriber’)->load($id)
->setCheckCode($code)
->unsubscribe();
$session->addSuccess($this->__(’You have been unsubscribed.’));
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
$session->addException($e, $e->getMessage());
}
catch (Exception $e) {
$session->addException($e, $this->__(’There was a problem with the un-subscription.’));
}
}
$this->_redirectReferer();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a can't leave a comment and this question isn't marked as solved yet, i'll assume you still need an answer.

I would suggest placing the `unsubscribe.phtml` file in `/template/newsletter/`

For step 2 you can use this code

`{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/unsubscribe.phtml"}}`

so the page will contain your form.

If you already figured out how to do this, please post an answer to your own question further on.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an idea to add an unsubscribe button next to the subscribe button (or allow for a variable in the block call that sets it to yes/no display) - this way you capture both